# Creating Databases in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

We were asked to create a database in sqlite3 and then create a table in it. I used this command:

```
 $sqlite3 me5.db
```

and tried to create a table with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE me5.petID(pet id PRIMARY KEY int(3), pet name varchar(10), pet type varchar(10), pet age int(3));
```

but it says that:

ERROR: near "CREATE" : syntax error

What could I have possible done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE petID(pet_id int(3) PRIMARY KEY, pet_name varchar(10), pet_type varchar(10), pet_age int(3));
```

1. you dont have to specify the database name because you're already using it after the command `sqlite3 me5.db`.
2. you have spaces in the names of the fields, which is not allowed. so i've put underscores instead of spaces.
3. use PRIMARY KEY after int(3)

Comment: Make sure to explain / emphasis the differences.

Comment: @bazi it works but it says now: "unknown database". did i miss something in creating the 'me5' database?

Comment: how about now. i've changed it now.